# Simple HTML5 app for mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, html, windows-phone

I want to build a simple app where everything is offline and mostly it is an informational app with info pages and list pages. What is the best way to build an HTML5 app for it so I can easily port it to different platforms? I'm looking for a free solution.

This developer had an HTML5 app so he just converted it to and Android app as mentioned in the answer: [Convert HTML5 into standalone Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840977/convert-html5-into-standalone-android-app). So, is that the way to go if I'm building one from scratch? Would it be just as easy to convert it to iOS?

Also, how does performance look for such an app on Android/iOS/Windows Phone? I mean would the page sliding animation and stuff be just as fluid as a native app given that it is so simple?

Comment: Have you looked at PhoneGap? It's probably the most popular platform that allows you to create mobile apps utilizing the a browser, and it's free to use.

Comment: I did not know it was free. If you put this as an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give PhoneGap a shot. It's probably the most popular platform that allows you to create mobile apps utilizing a browser, and it's free to use :)

Comment: I learned a lot about it and all setup with the free account. It says I can only have one private application. So, can I use this to create an application and then delete and create a new one or does it only allow one initial app? The FAQ or website in general doesn't mention it. Its OK if you're not sure, I can try it myself. I just didn't want to spoil my account I created with my primary email :). Also, I know it allows many public apps but I'm a little rusty with git as I haven't touched it in years.

Comment: Nevermind, found a test app on github for phonegap. That will do for now.